# Extract Text from PDF using PyMuPDF

Tags: pymupdf

I am trying to extract text from a specific portion of a PDF file.  From what I've found it sounds like PyMuPDF is the best option, and the below code came from the project's documentation.  The problem is that the text that is extracted is not from the rectangle.

```
"""
Script showing how to select only text that is contained in a given rectangle
on a page.
We use the page method 'get_text("words")' which delivers a list of all words.
Every item contains the word's rectangle (given by its coordinates, not as a
fitz.Rect in this case).
From this list we subselect words positioned in the given rectangle (or at
least intersect).
We sort this sublist by ascending y-ccordinate, and then by ascending x value.
Each original line of the rectangle is then reconstructed using the itertools
'groupby' function.
Remarks
-------
1. The script puts words in the same line, if the y1 value of their bbox are
   *almost* equal. Allowing more tolerance here is imaginable, e.g. by
   taking the fitz.IRect of the word rectangles instead.
2. Reconstructed lines will contain words with exactly one space between them.
   So any original multiple spaces will be lost.
3. Depending on your requirements, you can get away without any special script
   by using features new in version 1.17.7. They work on a by-character level,
   meaning they cut away parts of a word where necessary. On the other hand
   they are extremely simple to use: Page.get_textbox(rect), or
   Page.get_text("text", clip=rect), etc. is all you need.
"""
import fitz

def make_text(words):
    """Return textstring output of get_text("words").
    Word items are sorted for reading sequence left to right,
    top to bottom.
    """
    line_dict = {}  # key: vertical coordinate, value: list of words
    words.sort(key=lambda w: w[0])  # sort by horizontal coordinate
    for w in words:  # fill the line dictionary
        y1 = round(w[3], 1)  # bottom of a word: don't be too picky!
        word = w[4]  # the text of the word
        line = line_dict.get(y1, [])  # read current line content
        line.append(word)  # append new word
        line_dict[y1] = line  # write back to dict
    lines = list(line_dict.items())
    lines.sort()  # sort vertically
    return "\n".join([" ".join(line[1]) for line in lines])


doc = fitz.open("C:\\myFile.pdf")  # any supported document type
page = doc[0]  # we want text from this page

"""
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Identify the rectangle.
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
"""

rect = fitz.Rect(51, 181.4, 304.5, 239) 
# Now we have the rectangle ---------------------------------------------------

"""
Get all words on page in a list of lists. Each word is represented by:
[x0, y0, x1, y1, word, bno, lno, wno]
The first 4 entries are the word's rectangle coordinates, the last 3 are just
technical info (block number, line number, word number).
The term 'word' here stands for any string without space.
"""

words = page.get_text("words")  # list of words on page

"""
We will subselect from this list, demonstrating two alternatives:
(1) only words inside above rectangle
(2) only words insertecting the rectangle
The resulting sublist is then converted to a string by calling above funtion.
"""

# ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
# Case 1: select the words *fully contained* in the rect
# ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
mywords = [w for w in words if fitz.Rect(w[:4]) in rect]

print("Select the words strictly contained in rectangle")
print("------------------------------------------------")
print(make_text(mywords))

# ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
# Case 2: select the words *intersecting* the rect
# ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
mywords = [w for w in words if fitz.Rect(w[:4]).intersects(rect)]

print("\nSelect the words intersecting the rectangle")
print("-------------------------------------------")
print(make_text(mywords))
```

I created this code to test if the rectangle was on the correct area of the document and it is.

```
doc2 = fitz.open("C:\\myFile.pdf")  
# any supported document type
for page2 in doc2:
    # For every page, draw a rectangle on coordinates (1,1)(100,100)
    page2.draw_rect([51,181.4,304.5,239],  color = (0, 1, 0), width = 2)

doc2.save("C:\\myFile-2.pdf")
```

Answer (score 3):

You should use `get_textbox` function, so your code would be like:

```
doc2 = fitz.open("C:\\myFile.pdf")  
# any supported document type
for page2 in doc2:
    # For every page, draw a rectangle on coordinates (1,1)(100,100)
    print(page2.get_textbox(fitz.Rect([51,181.4,304.5,239])))
```

Comment: All text extraction and search functions support the `clip` parameter.
This will limit the respective function to a rectangular area as given by that parameter. So you can do
`page.get_text("words", clip=rect)`, `page.search_for(needle, clip=rect)`, etc.
But of course also `page.get_textbox(rect)` - as pointed out by @William-Castrillon.

Comment: Can I able to get the text format as same as in the PDF. Instead of giving back words separated by newline? @JorjMcKie